# Construction of a function with linear start and horizontal asymptote equal to 1

Tags: analysis, functions

I need a function which starts linearly at x=0 (with parameter settable slope !) and approaches horizontal asymptote of y=1 if x goes to infinity. Also the functions convergence speed to the asymptote should be settable with a parameter. Limit version of this function should be a linear function from x=0 to the asymptote and from there on a horizontal linear function equal to the asymptote y=1.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Notice that you have not asked a question, but merely stated that you need something. Please ask a clear question and maybe include what you have tried yourself. That helps others to write better answers.

Comment: I have tried function 1-exp(-k*x) but its convergence is to slow. Also function k*x/(k*x+1) has to slow convergence. Can it be improved, so that asymptote aproach speed can be set with an parameter ?